# Expectation of product of functions of two stochastic integrals

Tags: stochastic-processes, stochastic-calculus, brownian-motion, expected-value

Suppose $W_t$ and $B_t$ are two correlated standard Brownian processes such that  $\mathbb{E}[dW_t\cdot dB_t] = \rho dt$. Suppose that
$\sigma_1(s)$ and $\sigma_2(s)$ are two deterministic twice differentiable functions.

How can one compute expectation of the following product?

$$
\mathbb{E}\left[\exp\left(\int_0^t \sigma_1(s)dW_s\right)\cdot \int_0^t\sigma_2(s) dB_s \right]
$$

and more general case

$$
\mathbb{E}\left[f\left(\int_0^t \sigma_1(s)dW_s\right)\cdot \int_0^t\sigma_2(s) dB_s \right]
$$
where $f(x)$ is some nice infinitely differentiable function.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Please read this text about [how to ask a good question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question).

Comment: why do you think that you can compute it given the informations you gave ? Moreover, is $\sigma _i$ are random variable or deterministic ?

Comment: Yes, I forgot to mention $\sigma_1(s)$ and $\sigma_2(s)$ are deterministic differentiable nice functions

Comment: For the first case I think you could use Girsanov theorem somehow. Try adding adding and subtracting the time integral of $\sigma_1^2$, and then apply change of measure. Not sure how to deal with the correlation though.